Trouble Sending multipart/form-data with Python Requests
I'm trying to post three strings to a API/form. The webservice is called Nginx Proxy Manager if you are familiar. It don't really have API docs but it uses openapi 3.1.0. I'm trying to post to this section:
   "/nginx/certificates/{certID}/upload": {
  "post": {
    "operationId": "uploadCertificate",
    "summary": "Uploads a custom Certificate",
    "tags": [
      "Certificates"
    ],
    "security": [
      {
        "BearerAuth": [
          "certificates"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "in": "path",
        "name": "certID",
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "required": true,
        "example": 1
      }
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "description": "Certificate Files",
      "required": true,
      "content": {
        "multipart/form-data": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
              "certificate",
              "certificate_key"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "certificate": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "certificate_key": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "intermediate_certificate": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "200 response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "examples": {
              "default": {
                "value": {
                  "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIEYDCCAsigAwIBAgIRAPoSC0hvitb26ODMlsH6YbowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\ngZExHjAcBgNVBAoTFW1rY2VydCBkZXZlbG9wbWVudCBDQTEzMDEGA1UECwwqamN1\ncm5vd0BKYW1pZXMtTGFwdG9wLmxvY2FsIChKYW1pZSBDdXJub3cpMTowOAYDVQQD\nDDFta2NlcnQgamN1cm5vd0BKYW1pZXMtTGFwdG9wLmxvY2FsIChKYW1pZSBDdXJu\nb3cpMB4XDTI0MTAwOTA3MjIxN1oXDTI3MDEwOTA3MjIxN1owXjEnMCUGA1UEChMe\nbWtjZXJ0IGRldmVsb3BtZW50IGNlcnRpZmljYXRlMTMwMQYDVQQLDCpqY3Vybm93\nQEphbWllcy1MYXB0b3AubG9jYWwgKEphbWllIEN1cm5vdykwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3\nDQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC1n9j9C5Bes1ndqACDckERauxXVNKCnUlUM1bu\nGBx1xc+j2e2Ar23wUJJuWBY18VfT8yqfqVDktO2wrbmvZvLuPmXePOKbIKS+XXh+\n2NG9L5bDG9rwGFCRXnbQj+GWCdMfzx14+CR1IHgeYz6Cv/Si2/LJPCh/CoBfM4hU\nQJON3lxAWrWBpdbZnKYMrxuPBRfW9OuzTbCVXToQoxRAHiOR9081Xn1WeoKr7kVB\nIa5UphlvWXa12w1YmUwJu7YndnJGIavLWeNCVc7ZEo+nS8Wr/4QWicatIWZXpVaE\nOPhRoeplQDxNWg5b/Q26rYoVd7PrCmRs7sVcH79XzGONeH1PAgMBAAGjZTBjMA4G\nA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDATAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSB\n/vfmBUd4W7CvyEMl7YpMVQs8vTAbBgNVHREEFDASghB0ZXN0LmV4YW1wbGUuY29t\nMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBgQASwON/jPAHzcARSenY0ZGY1m5OVTYoQ/JWH0oy\nl8SyFCQFEXt7UHDD/eTtLT0vMyc190nP57P8lTnZGf7hSinZz1B1d6V4cmzxpk0s\nVXZT+irL6bJVJoMBHRpllKAhGULIo33baTrWFKA0oBuWx4AevSWKcLW5j87kEawn\nATCuMQ1I3ifR1mSlB7X8fb+vF+571q0NGuB3a42j6rdtXJ6SmH4+9B4qO0sfHDNt\nIImpLCH/tycDpcYrGSCn1QrekFG1bSEh+Bb9i8rqMDSDsYrTFPZTuOQ3EtjGni9u\nm+rEP3OyJg+md8c+0LVP7/UU4QWWnw3/Wolo5kSCxE8vNTFqi4GhVbdLnUtcIdTV\nXxuR6cKyW87Snj1a0nG76ZLclt/akxDhtzqeV60BO0p8pmiev8frp+E94wFNYCmp\n1cr3CnMEGRaficLSDFC6EBENzlZW2BQT6OMIV+g0NBgSyQe39s2zcdEl5+SzDVuw\nhp8bJUp/QN7pnOVCDbjTQ+HVMXw=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
                  "certificate_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nRrKmPK/msHKK/sVHiL+NFqo=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
                }
              }
            },
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "required": [
                "certificate",
                "certificate_key"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "certificate": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "minLength": 1
                },
                "certificate_key": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "minLength": 1
                },
                "intermediate_certificate": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "minLength": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},

This is what I currently have. I have tried a number of other things, this just seems the most correct to save space:
url = "https://api.example.com/api/nginx/certificates/1/upload"

# This header has been working in other calls.
headers = {
  "Authorization": f"Bearer " + api_key
}

# public, private, and chain are all strings
# I've tried tuples with  None and actual text like "chain.pem"
# I've tried a straight dict without the tuple
files = {
  "certificate": (None, public),
  "certificate_key": (None, private),
  "intermediate_certificate": (None, chain)
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
print(print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)))

{
  "error": "No files were uploaded"
}


Have you tried replacing None in each files keys with a hardcoded file name like
files = {"certificate": ("file.json", public),"certificate_key": ("file.json", private),"intermediate_certificate": ("file.json", chain)} Using None would drop the filename parameter from the request for those parts, hence it might not be recognized as uploaded file

Yes, I tried with "cert.pem", "chain.pem", and "privkey.pem". It produces the same error.

This ended up not being the this code. The server requires the certificate object be created first, take the ID, then upload. I has assumed that I could just specify an unused ID to create the object at the same time.
